# What is meant by input and output bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, change-of-basis

$\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle}$

Exercise 2.2: (Matrix representations: example) Suppose $V$ is a vector space
with basis vectors $\qr0$ and $\qr1$, and $A$ is a linear operator from $V$ to $V$ such that $A\qr{0}$ = $\qr1$ and $A\qr1 = \qr0$. Give a matrix representation for $A$, with respect to the input basis $\qr0,\qr1$, and the output basis $\qr0,\qr1$. Find input and output bases which give rise to a different matrix representation of $A$.

I had never heard of the terms "input basis" and "output basis".  Nevertheless, the first part of the exercise is easy enough and I can see that a matrix representing the linear transform is just an $2x2$ identity matrix with the rows swapped.  But how can I find input and output bases which give rise to a different matrix representation of $A$?  Can you show me with a concrete example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is a linear map between two vector spaces. Given a linear map, $\phi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, there are multiple ways to represent it as an $n\times m$ matrix depending on what basis you use. You can read more about this [here](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~yvorobet/MATH304-503/Lect2-12web.pdf), if you want to confirm that you understand this. When it says “unit basis” and “output basis” its talking about the basis for the vector space that the (input/output) is coming from.

You’re correct that the answer with respect to the given basis is the transpose of the identity matrix. Suppose now you were working with $|0\rangle$ and $|\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ for both the input and the output bases instead. Do you see how the matrix would change? **Hint:** what’s the relationships between the old bases and the new bases.

——-

Let’s say you have a linear transformation, $T$. We can write it as a matrix, $A=[T]_\beta^\gamma$ where $\beta$ is the input basis and $\gamma$ is the output basis. To find $A$, we use the following formula:

$$A=[T]_\beta^\gamma=\big[[T(v_1)]_\gamma\;[T(v_2]_\gamma\;\ldots\;[T(v_k)]_\gamma\big]$$

Here $[T(v_i)]_\gamma$ is the matrix representation in the basis $\gamma$ of the vector that is the linear transformation $T$ applied to the $i^{th}$ basis vector of $\beta$. Therefore $[T(v_i)]_\gamma=\varphi_\gamma(T(v_i))$ where $\varphi_\gamma$ is the transformation that is a change of basis into basis $\gamma$.

So let’s do an example. Say that we want to keep the input basis the same but change the output basis to $\gamma=\{(0,1),(2,0)\}$. Your problem doesn’t name the linear operator (only the matrix) so let’s say that the operator is called $T$ and it’s representation in the standard basis is $A$. We wish to find $A’$, the representation in our new basis. From our formula, we know that the columns of $A’$ are $[T(0,1)]_\gamma$ and $[T(1,0)]_\gamma$. We know that $T$ switches the order, so the columns are $w_1=(1,0)$ and $w_2=(0,1)$. But those vectors are written with respect to the standard basis, not with respect to $\gamma$! Luckily we can easily write them with respect to gamma by seeing that $(0,1)=0\cdot w_1+1\cdot w_2$ and $(2,0)=2\cdot w_1+0\cdot w_2$. Therefore with respect to basis $\gamma$ we have that the columns are $(0,1)$ and $(2,0)$, so our matrix is

$$A’=\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I believe you meant to write $|0\rangle$ and $|\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ as my new basis?  Gonna work on this and get back to you.  (I can be very slow at math!)

Comment: @R.Chopin Indeed I did! Lemme know if you want a hint.

Comment: $\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle}$Hi, @Stella.  My question is now this.  If $\qr0$ and $\qr{\frac{1}{2}}$ are now my basis, what am I to expect from the transformation $A$?  It maps $\qr0$ to $\qr1$ and $\qr1$ to $\qr0$.  I don't know to what A maps $\qr{\frac{1}{2}}$.  If I did know, then I get a matrix in the same way I got the first matrix.  More than a hint, I'd like a little linear algebra culture. :-) I don't seem to be on the same page as you and the exercise.

Comment: @R.Chopin The function is linear, so $\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)=\phi(\frac{1}{2}x)$

Comment: $\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle}$ @Stella, what is meant by $\qr{\frac{1}{2}}$?  I know $\qr0$ is the column vector $(1, 0)$ and that $\qr1$ is the column vector $(0, 1)$.  So I think $\qr{\frac{1}{2}}$ must equal $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ because maybe $\qr{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\qr{1} = (0, \frac{1}{2}).$  Does that make sense?

Comment: $\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle}$I still feel lost, but here's my first try at an answer.  What is the matrix representation for the basis $\{\qr0, \qr{\frac{1}{2}}\}$?  I say it's $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$  Because: $A$ takes $\qr0$ to $\qr1$ and $A$ takes $\qr{\frac{1}{2}}$ to $\frac{1}{2}\qr0$.  So $A$ swaps the components of its input, but also scales to half the first component (of its input).

Comment: @R.Chopin That’s actually not what I had in mind with that notation. This might be entirely on me misunderstanding the notation, as bra-ket notation is uncommon and I haven’t used it in several years. I’ll edit the OP with a comprehensive example.

Comment: @R.Chopin I’ve now added an example. Can you follow along in the example?

Comment: Maybe.  Let me interpret your matrix.  It takes a vector $(x, y)$ (on the standard basis) to the vector $(2y, x)$.  This means that the vector $(x, y)$ must be swaped and the first coordinate must be doubled (after the swap) to mean the same thing we had before, $(x, y)$, in the new basis $\{(0,1), (2,0)\}$.

Comment: While I investigated your example, I also asked a new [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610424/why-does-the-method-of-getting-a-transition-matrix-seems-reversed-to-me).  Maybe you'd like to consider it too?