# Implicit equation of a rotated ellipse

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, conic-sections, curves

I am trying to determine analytically what the curve given by the implicit equation $(1)$ would look like:

$$\left(x-\left(3+\frac{y}{3}\right)t\right)^{2}+y^{2}=1 \tag{1}$$

where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is a positive parameter.

**My attempt**

I see that for $t=0$ it is a circumference centred at the origin. Indeed, plotting it I see that for $t\neq0$ it represents rotated ellipses.

How could this be deduced analytically from the implicit equation of the curve?

[image]

Comment: If you expand the equation you clearly get a [conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form) and since the discriminant is negative for all $t$ it will be an ellipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing:

$$\left(x-\left(3+\frac{y}{3}\right)t\right)^{2}+y^{2}=1$$

in this way:

$$\left(x-\frac{t}{3}y-3t\right)^{2}+y^{2}=1,$$

you get an ellipse (whatever $t$) as the image of unit circle

$$X^2+Y^2=1$$

by affine change of coordinates:

$$\binom{X}{Y}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-t/3\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\binom{x}{y}+\binom{-3t}{0}$$

This change of coordinates must be written in the **inverse** way (see alias/alibi transformations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2610424)) in order to be interpreted as the (affine) transform applied to the unit circle that generates the ellipse with parameter $t$:

$$\binom{x}{y}=\begin{pmatrix}1&t/3\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\binom{X}{Y}+\binom{3t}{0}$$

explaining the combined effect of a distortion of the unit circle (brought by the triangular matrix) followed by an horizontal translation.

Remark: this distorsion is called a [shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix) in the direction of $x$ axis, or sometimes a transvection.

Comment: I just added the name "shear" to my answer.