# Using a rotation matrix to rotate the graph of a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, graphing-functions, rotations

I understand where the following matrices come from and how they geometrically rotate a point (x, y) counterclockwise/clockwise by $θ$

$\begin{bmatrix}\cosθ&-\sinθ\\\sinθ&\cosθ\end{bmatrix} $ for counterclockwise and

$\begin{bmatrix}\cosθ&\sinθ\\-\sinθ&\cosθ\end{bmatrix} $ for clockwise

For example, I want to rotate the graph ${y} = x^{2}$ by 45° counterclockwise. By appying this matrix to any point (x, y),

$\begin{bmatrix}\cos45°&-\sin45°\\\sin45°&\cos45°\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y\end{bmatrix}$

So, $x$ moves to $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y)$ and $y$ moves to $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y)$

If I plug these values into ${y} = x^{2}$, it yields the following graph:

[image]

As you can see, despite plugging in the **counterclockwise-rotated** points, the graph was rotated **clockwise** by 45°.

**So my question is:** Why does plugging in the counterclockwise-rotated points result in a graph that is rotated clockwise?

I know that in order to rotate the graph counterclockwise you just have to input the points rotated counterclockwise, but I am having trouble understanding why, conceptually.

Comment: Applying the matrix to a point, rotate it, but making the substitution in the variables is equivalent to rotate *the axes*.

Comment: See the answer by GEdgar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2610424/305862) with terms "alias" and "alibi".

Answer (score 2):

The rotation is properly applied to the original axes $(x,y)$ *counterclockwise* and for this reason, setting the new axes in the original position, apparently the graph rotates *clockwise*, according to the following sketch

[image]